# separators in between li tag is not having full height

Tags: html, css

[image].

This is what i am trying to achieve

I want the separator to be extended to full height. that is, it should cover the entire nav bar's height.

Html markup is as follows.

```css
.mynav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">TRENDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">DESIGNERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MEMBERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SEARCH</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MY ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the CSS .mynav and the tags that are wrapping the nav bar. Without this, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Would you mind giving some more details and a working (or broken) example on jsfiddle?

Comment: .mynav{
     margin-top: 27px;
   }

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has updated his question this would be the solution

[image]

```css
.mynav ul {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.mynav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline
}
.mynav a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px
}
.mynav li:not(:last-child) a {
  box-shadow: 1px 0 red
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">TRENDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">DESIGNERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MEMBERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SEARCH</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MY ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you can use [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.mynav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative
}
.mynav li:not(:last-child):before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">TRENDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">DESIGNERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MEMBERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SEARCH</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MY ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```css
.mynav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative
}
.mynav li:not(:last-child){
  box-shadow: 1px 0 red
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">TRENDS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">DESIGNERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MEMBERS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SEARCH</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">MY ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nearly 10k :) I think an answer should always contain a pseudo element :)

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be `display: inline-block` if you wish to add padding to the top/bottom of your `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the padding to the `A` tag instead of `Li` tag :

```
.mynav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.mynav li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add `width:13%;` or something which will fit your width.

Check the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xf3rgte7/)